# How to get RAM Size , bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, ram, bootloader, osdev

I was gonna ask how to get the Total RAM Size , and Usable RAM Size in the bootloader. As of right now i know how to get the lower memory. But i cant print that to the screen for some reason , as it is kept in the ax register. This is what i have so far:

```
[BITS 16] ; BootLoader always starts 16 BIT Moded

    jmp main_bootloader ; Jump to Main Bootloader

     ;************** INITALIZED VARIABLES *********************;
      string db 'BoneOS Loading . . .', 0x0
      string2 db 'Starting of 16Bit Bootloader' , 0x0
      press_to_cont db 'Press any key to continue . . .' , 0x0
      carry_flag_err db ' CARRY FLAG HAS BEEN SET! ERROR ' , 0x0
      magic_number equ 0x534D4150
      limit dw 0
      base  dw 0
      low_memory dd 0
      answer resb 64
     ;*********************************************************;  

     ;******************** GDTs *****************************;


         null_descriptor :
            dd 0                ; null descriptor--just fill 8 bytes with zero
            dd 0 

        ; Notice that each descriptor is exactally 8 bytes in size. THIS IS IMPORTANT.
        ; Because of this, the code descriptor has offset 0x8.

         code_descriptor:           ; code descriptor. Right after null descriptor
            dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
            dw 0                ; base low
            db 0                ; base middle
            db 10011010b            ; access
            db 11001111b            ; granularity
            db 0                ; base high

        ; Because each descriptor is 8 bytes in size, the Data descritpor is at offset 0x10 from
        ; the beginning of the GDT, or 16 (decimal) bytes from start.

         data_descriptor:           ; data descriptor
            dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
            dw 0                ; base low
            db 0                ; base middle
            db 10010010b            ; access
            db 11001111b            ; granularity
            db 0                ; base high

        end_of_gdt: 
            toc: 
                dw end_of_gdt - null_descriptor - 1     ; limit (Size of GDT)
                dd null_descriptor          ; base of GDT   

        load_gdt:
            lgdt [toc]

        .done:
            ret


     ;*********************************************************;

     ;*************** LABELS FOR MAIN **************************;
        print_char_boot:
            mov ah, 0Eh ; Code For BIOS To Print Char 0Eh

        .repeat:
            lodsb ; Load Byte From SI Register
            cmp al, 0 ; Compare AL With 0 If so Done
            je .done 
            int 10h ; Call Interupt. Checks AH Register for code 0EH = Print char
            jmp .repeat ; Loop Back

        .done:
            ret ; Return to previous code


        print_new_line:
               mov al, 0    ; null terminator '\0' 
               ;Adds a newline break '\n'
               mov ah, 0x0E
               mov al, 0x0D
               int 0x10
               mov al, 0x0A 
               int 0x10
               ret

        get_pressed_key:
            mov ah, 0
            int 0x16  ;BIOS Call. Key goes to al register
            ret 
        GET_RAM_SIZE:

        reboot:
            mov si, press_to_cont
            call print_char_boot
            call get_pressed_key ; Gets Pressed Key

            int 19h ;Reboot
            ret

        enable_A20: ; Enabling A20 Line For Full Memory
            cli ; Stop Interupts before doing so

            call    a20wait ; a20wait call
            mov     al,0xAD ; Send 0xAD Command to al register
            out     0x64,al ; Send command 0xad (disable keyboard).

            call    a20wait ; When controller ready for command
            mov     al,0xD0 ; Send 0xD0 Command to al register
            out     0x64,al ; Send command 0xd0 (read from input)

            call    a20wait2 ; When controller ready for command
            in      al,0x60 ; Read input from keyboard
            push    eax ; Save Input by pushing to stack

            call    a20wait ; When controller ready for command
            mov     al,0xD1 ; mov 0xD1 Command to al register
            out     0x64,al ; Set command 0xd1 (write to output)

            call    a20wait ; When controller ready for command
            pop     eax ; Pop Input from Keyboard
            or      al,2 ; Mov 0xD3 to al register
            out     0x60,al ; Set Command 0xD3

            call    a20wait ; When controller ready for command
            mov     al,0xAE ; Mov Command 0xAE To al register
            out     0x64,al ; Write command 0xae (enable keyboard)

            call    a20wait ; When controller ready for command
            sti ; Enable Interrupts after enabling A20 Line
            ret

                a20wait:
                    in      al,0x64 ; input from 0x64 port, goes to al register
                    test    al,2 ; compares al register with 2
                    jnz     a20wait ; If it is zero loop again
                    ret


                a20wait2:
                    in      al,0x64 ; input from 0x64 port, goes to al register
                    test    al,1 ; compares al register with 2
                    jz      a20wait2 ; If it is zero loop again
                    ret 


            get_lower_memory:
                clc ; Clears Carry Flag
                int 0x12 ; BIOS Call Request Lower Memory Size in KB
                jc .err ; If Carry Flag Has Been Set , the system its running on dosent support this
                jmp .done ; If Sucessfull ax register contains contiguous low memory in KB

            .err:
                times 5 call print_new_line ; Prints New Line
                mov si, carry_flag_err
                call print_char_boot 
                jmp .repeat

            .done:
            ret

        .repeat:
            jmp .repeat





;**************************************************************;


;*******************'MAIN' BOOTLOADER FUNCTION ****************;
main_bootloader:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, string ; si register usefull for lodsb command
    call print_char_boot ; Call print_char_boot label below
    call print_new_line ; Prints New Line
    mov si, string2
    call print_char_boot 
    times 2 call print_new_line
    ; Enable A20 Line
    call enable_A20

    call get_lower_memory ; Get Low Memory


    mov si,ax
    call print_char_boot 
    times 5 call print_new_line

    call reboot ; Reboot

    ;call null_descriptor


    jmp $ ; Infinite Loop 
    ;Bootloader gets infinite loop 
    ;Incase No Infinite Loop in Kernel

;****************************************************************;  


;************************* BOOTLOADER REQUIREMENTS **************;  
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Has to be 512 bytes .. Repeats 510 byes to make it so
dw 0xAA55 ; BootLoader Sig. To Validate this is a bootloader
;

****************************************************************;
```

As you can see on my main i am `call get_lower_memory ; Get Low Memory` , to get the low memory. But i have tested printing ax register and nothing shows up on screen. And i also dont know how to get total and usable ram , in the System. Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Use INT 15h, EAX = E820h to get the memory map of the system in order to find the regions of memory you can use.

Comment: If `ax` contains the amount of low memory in kilobytes then what happens when  the two statements `mov si, ax` and `call print_char_boot` are executed?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though the question stated in the body of your post is more about printing the value of a register than it is about detecting the memory available to the system, I'll just be loyal to the title question, and present an example of how to detect the system memory map.

As a bonus, a function to display a 32 bit unsigned integer as hex numeral is supplied, along with a very primitive *print* that supports placeholders.

---

Detecting memory is not an easy task, it requires full knowledge of the hardware installed<sup>1</sup> and cannot be done without it (see [Detecting memory](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)#Manual_Probing) on OSDev).
As a simple example think of an [aliased memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Hardware_aliasing), the software cannot detect that without any involved and slow method.

Having acknowledged that a cooperation with the BIOS is mandatory, we can see what services are available to a 16 bit real mode bootloader.
The above mentioned page of OSDev about [detecting memory](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)) already have a list of services dedicated to the titled purpose, to which reference is made.

We will focus on the [Int 15/AX=E820h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1741.htm) service.
It's use is to return a list of memory range along with their description.
Each call return the next descriptor, using `ebx` to keep track of the advancement. The register `ebx` should be treated as an opaque value.
Despite the description in the *Ralf's Brown Interrupt List*, descriptors can be 24 bytes long, so it's better to use that length and eventually check the value returned in `ecx` to tell 20/24 bytes descriptors apart.

---

Once we have the list of descriptors they can be used by the routine dictated to allocating memory<sup>2</sup>.
It is worth nothing tow things:

1. The descriptors are **not** ordered. Some buggy BIOS may return **overlapped** areas (in such case make the most conservative choice).
2. There may be **gaps** even once the descriptors are ordered. Ranges where there is no memory mapped are not reported, this is the case for the standard hole (ranging from 0a0000h to 0fffffh).
3. Areas explicitly reserved by the BIOS (e.g. the shadow area from 0f0000h to 0fffffh) are reported though.

In the example below the descriptors are printed on the screen along with the total amount of non reserved memory<sup>3</sup>.

By the way, you can use the `itoa16` function to print a 32 bit value in `EAX`, supposed you changed the the way characters are printed on the screen.

```
BITS 16

;Set CS to a known value
;This makes the offsets in memory and in source match 
;(e.g. __START__ is at offset 5h in the binary image and at addres 7c0h:0005h)

jmp 7c0h:__START__

__START__:
 ;Set all the segments to CS 
 mov ax, cs
 mov ds, ax
 mov es, ax
 mov ss, ax
 xor sp, sp

 ;Clear the screen
 mov ax, 03h
 int 10h

 ;FS will be used to write into the text buffer
 push 0b800h
 pop fs

 ;SI is the pointer in the text buffer 
 xor si, si 

 ;These are for the INT 15 service
 mov di, baseAddress                    ;Offset in ES where to save the result
 xor ebx, ebx                           ;Start from beginning
 mov ecx, 18h                           ;Length of the output buffer (One descriptor at a time)

 ;EBP will count the available memory 
 xor ebp, ebp 

_get_memory_range:
 ;Set up the rest of the registers for INT 15 
 mov eax, 0e820h 
 mov edx, 534D4150h
 int 15h
 jc _error 

 ;Has somethig been returned actually?
 test ecx, ecx
 jz _next_memory_range

 ;Add length (just the lower 32 bits) to EBP if type = 1 or 3 
 mov eax, DWORD [length]

 ;Avoid a branch (just for the sake of less typing)

 mov edx, DWORD [type]         ;EDX = 1        | 2        | 3        | 4   (1 and 3 are available memory)
 and dx, 01h                   ;EDX = 1        | 0        | 1        | 0 
 dec edx                       ;EDX = 0        | ffffffff | 0        | ffffffff 
 not edx                       ;EDX = ffffffff | 0        | ffffffff | 0 
 and eax, edx                  ;EAX = length   | 0        | length   | 0 

 add ebp, eax

 ;Show current memory descriptor 
 call show_memory_range

_next_memory_range:
 test ebx, ebx 
 jnz _get_memory_range

 ;Print empty line
 push WORD strNL 
 call print 

 ;Print total memory available 
 push ebp 
 push WORD strTotal
 call print 

 cli
 hlt

_error:
 ;Print error
 push WORD strError
 call print

 cli 
 hlt


 ;Memory descriptor returned by INT 15 
 baseAddress dq 0
 length      dq 0
 type        dd 0
 extAttr     dd 0

 ;This function just show the string strFormat with the appropriate values 
 ;taken from the mem descriptor 
 show_memory_range:
  push bp
  mov bp, sp

  ;Extend SP into ESP so we can use ESP in memory operanda (SP is not valid in any addressing mode)
  movzx esp, sp 

  ;Last percent
  push DWORD [type]

  ;Last percents pair
  push DWORD [length]
  push DWORD [length + 04h]

  ;Add baseAddress and length (64 bit addition)
  push DWORD [baseAddress]
  mov eax, DWORD [length]
  add DWORD [esp], eax               ;Add (lower DWORD)
  push DWORD [baseAddress + 04h]
  mov eax, DWORD [length + 04h]
  adc DWORD [esp], 0                 ;Add with carry (higher DWORD)

  ;First percents pair
  push DWORD [baseAddress]
  push DWORD [baseAddress + 04h]

  push WORD strFormat
  call print

  mov sp, bp                         ;print is a mixed stdcall/cdecl, remove the arguments

  pop bp
  ret

 ;Strings, here % denote a 32 bit argument printed as hex 
 strFormat db "%% - %% (%%) - %", 0
 strError  db "Som'thing is wrong :(", 0
 strTotal  db "Total amount of memory: %", 0 
 ;This is tricky, see below 
 strNL     db 0

 ;Show a 32 bit hex number
 itoa16:
  push cx
  push ebx

  mov cl, 28d

 .digits:
   mov ebx, eax
   shr ebx, cl
   and bx, 0fh                     ;Get current nibble

   ;Translate nibble (digit to digital)
   mov bl, BYTE [bx + hexDigits]

   ;Show it 
   mov bh, 0ch
   mov WORD [fs:si], bx
   add si, 02h   

   sub cl, 04h
  jnc .digits

  pop ebx
  pop cx
  ret

  hexDigits db "0123456789abcdef"

  ;This function is a primitive printf, where the only format is % to show a 32 bit 
  ;hex number 
  ;The "cursor" is kept by SI.
  ;SI is always aligned to lines, so 1) never print anything bigger than 80 chars
  ;2) successive calls automatically print into their own lines 
  ;3) SI is assumed at the beginning of a line 

  ;Args
  ;Format
  print:
   push bp
   mov bp, sp

   push di
   push cx

   mov di, WORD [bp+04h]      ;String 
   mov cx, 80*2               ;How much to add to SI to reach the next line 

   add bp, 06h                ;Pointer to var arg 

  .scan:

    ;Read cur char 
    mov al, [di]
    inc di

    ;Format?
    cmp al, '%'
    jne .print

    ;Get current arg and advance index 
    mov eax, DWORD [bp]
    add bp, 04h
    ;Show the number 
    call itoa16

    ;We printed 8 chars (16 bytes) 
    sub cx, 10h

   jmp .scan    

  .print:
    ;End of string?
    test al, al
    je .end

    ;Normal char, print it 
    mov ah, 0ch
    mov WORD [fs:si], ax
    add si, 02h
    sub cx, 02h

   jmp .scan   


  .end:
   add si, cx

   pop cx
   pop di

   pop bp
   ret 02h

   ;Signature
   TIMES 510 - ($-$$) db 0 
   dw 0aa55h
```

---

In a 64MiB Bochs emulated machine, the result is

[image: Memory map of a 64 MiB machine]

Where the format is *start - end (size) - type*.

Using a picture we get

[image: Map]

The total amount of memory computed is 66.711.552 bytes or 64 MiB - 1 KiB (EBDA) - 96 KiB (Shadow area) - 288 KiB (Standard Hole).
ACPI tables are considered available as they are reclaimable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Particularly of what was the part of the north bridge, now iMC, dedicated to handling the DRAM. Information about installed modules (Mostly DIMM and  mobile variants) can be retrieved through [SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) using either a [SMBus](http://smbus.org/specs/smbus20.pdf) or [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) controller.
The BIOS then consider the enabled memory mapped devices and the bus topology (along with its routing and bridging information) and exposes all this through the  the [SMBios specification](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf).

<sup>2</sup> Since it will use some sort of range descriptors anyway, eventually a format conversion is performed.

<sup>3</sup> This count includes the newly type 5 (Bad memory) range.

Comment: Ok first off , thanks a lot for this awesome response! Ok so , as stated in picture , the total number is 03f9f000 , which corresponds to 1,073,347,584 . Is this in KB , Mb , millibyte, etc..? And another question , I recently got  0xD5C02700 -> 3,586,139,904 , for GRUB . What units is that in? Here is the test i had for the 3 billion one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzE5dkmh9Vs . Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Dsafds 3f9f000h is 66.711.552. Unit for memory is the minimum addressable item: byte (for x86). 3.586139.904 bytes are slightly more than 3 GiB.

Comment: Is that the Total RAM , or Usable RAM ?

Comment: @Dsafds Usable RAM.

Comment: Margaret : last question. Im kinda scepitcal about the amount of RAM It tells me it gives me.. because as you can see on above viedo when i print it as a decimal it gives me these wierd characters(total RAM That is) . Do you know why this happenes?